# Hide header referer for external javascript

Tags: javascript, header, referer

I have a external tracking code on my confirmation page, but the url on my page also has personal information stored.

How can I prevent that the header referer get send (my page is not html5).

Here an example of the external link

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.externalsite.com/trackingcode.php"></script>

><noscript>
 <img src="https://www.externalsite.com/trackingcode.php" width=1 height=1 border=0>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Isn't that kinda missing the point of using tracking code?

Comment: No the tracking code works with cookies. So the URL doesn't matter....Hope so...